# Proving a proposition regarding sigma algebras

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\{ X_{\alpha} \}_{\alpha \in A } $ be any collection and $X = \prod_{\alpha \in A} X_{\alpha} $. Let $\pi_{\alpha}: X \to X_{\alpha} $ be coordinate maps and let $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $ be sigma algebras on $X_{\alpha} $. The product sigma algebra on $X$ is generated then by   $ \mathcal{R} = \{ \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_{\alpha} ) : E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{M}_{\alpha}, \alpha \in A\}$, and we denote it by $\bigotimes_{\alpha \in A} \mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $.

#### Proposition:

Suppose $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $ is generated by $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha} $(that is, $\sigma( \mathcal{E}_{\alpha} ) = \mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $ ) for all $\alpha \in A $. Then $\bigotimes_{\alpha} \mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $ is generated by $\mathcal{F} = \{ \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_{\alpha}): E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{E}_{\alpha} \} $.

#### Try:

Take an element from $\mathcal{F}$: Say $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1} (E_{\alpha} ) $ and $E_{\alpha} \in \mathcal{E}_{\alpha} $. We know $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha} \subseteq \sigma(  \mathcal{E}_{\alpha} ) $ and this, by hypothesis, equals $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $. Hence, we obtain that $\mathcal{F} \subseteq \mathcal{P} \subseteq \bigotimes_{\alpha} \mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $ which implies that $ \sigma( \mathcal{F}) \subseteq \mathcal{P} \subseteq \bigotimes_{\alpha} \mathcal{M}_{\alpha} $

I am stuck trying to prove that $\bigotimes_{\alpha} \mathcal{M}_{\alpha} \subseteq \sigma( \mathcal{F} ) $. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Let $f:X\to Y$ be a function and $\mathcal{M}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$, then prove that the set
$$
\{V \subset Y : f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{M}\}
$$
is a $\sigma$-algebra on $Y$.

Now consider your problem: it suffices to prove that $\mathcal{R}\subset \sigma(\mathcal{F})$. So choose an element of the form $\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_{\alpha}) \in \mathcal{R}$, and consider the set
$$
S := \{V \subset X_{\alpha} : \pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(V) \in \sigma(\mathcal{F})\}
$$
By the previous lemma, $S$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X_{\alpha}$ that contains $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha}$. Hence, $S$ contains $\mathcal{M}_{\alpha}$, and in particular, $E_{\alpha} \in S$. Thus,
$$
\pi_{\alpha}^{-1}(E_{\alpha}) \in \sigma(\mathcal{F})
$$

Comment: Why does $S$ contains $\mathcal{E}_{\alpha} $ ?

Comment: Perhaps the down-voter would like to explain him/herself?

Comment: I downvoted because you are just parroting what is written in Folland's Book.

Comment: Great minds think alike. In any case, down-voting a correct answer for such silly reasons is generally considered rather petty.

Comment: @easy Not everyone has the book, so this is rather a helpful answer.